# How to simulate pressing the enter key while using screen through PHP?

Tags: php, linux, bash, exec, gnu-screen

I'm trying to create a bash script that reloads or stops my Minecraft server. I'm creating this so I can run it through PHP using `shell_exec()`. So far, I've not been able to figure out how to simulate pressing the enter key.

I've tried:

```
screen -S minecraft -X stuff $"reload\n"

screen -S minecraft -X stuff "reload"

screen -S minecraft -X stuff $'reload\n'
```

The very last option out of those 3 works when I run it from bash, but executing it through PHP prints

```
>$reload\n
```

And it never hits 'enter', so the command never goes through even though it's typed wrong.

I have www-data in the sudoers file as able to execute this bash file. The screen is running on another account (minecraft). Here is my PHP-side code:

```
echo " Your account has been verified. Server reload command called.";
$output = exec("sudo -u minecraft /var/www/pditbp/commands/reload.sh");
echo "The output of running the <b>reload</b> command has produced: ";
echo $output;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This has been solved guys. Thanks to anyone though for checking it out. I will post the answer after my 8 hour wait as I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: Thanks @Edwin. I've trimmed it from your answer, but if you want  to copy and paste it, it's in [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24714082/revisions).